# Can't get Axapta.CreateAxaptaObject() to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, axapta

I have a Web Service for my ASP.NET MVC 3 app which creates a new Sales Order in AX. In AX I have created an OnlineOrder class which has 1 method for now. It is to generate a Sales Reference. Below is the code in my web service:

```
public AxaptaObject order;

        public void CreateOrder()
        {
            AxaptaStart();
            order = Axapta.CreateAxaptaObject("OnlineOrder");
            AxaptaStop();
        }

        public string GetSalesRef(string username, string delivery, string reference)
        {

            AxaptaStart();
            string number = order.Call("orderCreate", username, delivery, reference).ToString();
            AxaptaStop();
            return number;
        }
```

Then in my Controller I call these methods:

```
            client.CreateOrder();

            string number = client.GetSalesRef(user.Username, order.deliverymethod, order.custorder).ToString();
```

This doesn't work and there is no exception info to show, its just a blank message. I believe the `order` AxaptaObject is not of type `OnlineOrder` so it can't call those methods. How would I instantiate the object to use the `orderCreate` method?

EDIT:

If I do:

```
        public string CreateOrder(string username, string delivery, string reference)
        {
            AxaptaStart();
            order = Axapta.CreateAxaptaObject("OnlineOrder");
            string number = order.Call("orderCreate", username, delivery, reference).ToString();
            AxaptaStop();
            return number;
        }
```

This works, but this isn't a valid solution as I'd like to add more methods to my OnlineOrder object in the future and I dont want to call them all in 1 method on my web service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will never work as the `order` object is sort of closed when you call the `AxaptaStop` method.

I will suggest creating a class implementing [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), then call `AxaptaStop` in the `Dispose` method. The `AxaptaStart` call could go to the constructor. This will allow you to scope the AX context like:

```
using (var axWrap = new AxWrap())
{
    var order = axWrap.onlineOrder();
    var number = axWrap.orderCreate(order, username, delivery, reference);
}
```

The `Dispose` is automatically called by the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: But this would also require this to all be in 1 method on my webservice wouldnt it? How would I use the same "order" object in a different method?

Comment: No it would not. The `order` object can be returned from the wrapper method as in the example (or saved in a member variable). All calls to COM is hidden in your wrapper class hiding the ugly details. It also makes your code from the caller look nice(r).